# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to have my lambda putting/updating objects in my s3 bucket. I have not changed any default bucket setting and attached the below role iam policy to the lambda.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

What I don't understand is that `get` operations seems to work, but `put` doesn't

```
    logger.info("before boto")
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3'
                      )

    objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev')
    
    logger.info("entering debug list")
    for obj in objects.get('Contents',[]):
        logger.info(f"{obj['Key']}")

    some_binary_data = b'let me in'
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    object = s3.Object('my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev', 'whatwithpermission.txt')
    object.put(Body=some_binary_data)
```

the above has generated the following error message

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong? Cos I thought i've granted all possible s3 permission to the lambda.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arn `arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev` if for **bucket** only, not for objects. Thus any object level operations, such as `put` will fail. Proper object level Arn is `arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev/*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out on the permissions required for objects, you've to add the resource `arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev/*` for that.

So your policy ideally look like this:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my_custom_bucket_name_for_dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added the new resource line and it still doesnt work. Will update with more info once i have time to do more debugging.

Comment: After verifying policies, iam user credentials you're using, and then verify bucket policy as well